# Unable to connect to WiFi on windows 10

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

I’m able to connect other devices to the Netgear router but the Windows 10 running on a MacBook Pro (using bootcamp) often fails to connect. I’ve tried resetting the network setup in windows preferences, forgetting the network, removing and uninstalling the WiFi device driver in device manager.

Every time it wants the WiFi password, which I provide, only to say “unable to connect to this network”. I’ve ran the network troubleshooter and it determined that there was an unknown error. Welcome to 1995.

Windows 10.0.19042

EDIT:
When I go into Mac OS it connects to the WiFi. I’ve also managed to briefly connect to WiFi on Windows using the “Manually connect to a wireless network” in the Network and Sharing Center, and under “advanced” I enabled “activate FIPS (Federal Information Processing Standards”. However, after a few minutes it disconnected again.

Comment: Can other devices or mobile phones connect to the same network？

Comment: @Sunny, yes, see first sentence.

Comment: Can you ping the Wi-Fi router Default Gateway successfully?

Comment: Yes. This was resolved by turning the equipment off for multiple hours. This has happened before and might happen again, so frustrating.